# React app slows down and JS Heap gets bigger. How to find memory leak?

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, styled-components

I'll try to simplify this as much as possible. I have a "create an avatar" page which contains a "color chooser" component. Each time you click it a function generates a new random color and that color is then fed back into the props of the color chooser component so it can be used as the background color.

If I click the button as fast as I can it swaps the colors quickly at first but then starts to slow down to the point where the app becomes unusable, even if I navigate to a new page.

Dev tools shows that the JS heap and nodes count just keeps getting bigger and bigger and I can't stop this happening however much I simplify it.

[image: Dev Tools Profile]

Here is a minimal exmaple of my page component and my color chooser component.

**Page**

```
const Component: React.FC<Props> = (props) => {

    const [mode, setMode] = useState('avatar')
    const [avatarColor, setAvatarColor] = useState(initialColor)

    // Color Clicked
    const colorClicked = useCallback(() => {
        let newColor = pickRandomColor()
        setAvatarColor(newColor as string)
    }, [])


    return (
        <StyledPage {...props}>
            {mode === 'avatar' && 
                <AvatarColorChooser
                    color={avatarColor}
                    onClick={colorClicked}
                />
            }
        </StyledPage>
    )

}

export default Component

const StyledPage = styled.div`
    // Styles
`
```

**Color Chooser**

```
const Component: React.FC<Props> = (props) => {

    return (
        <StyledComponent color={props.color}>
            <button type="button" onClick={props.onClick}>
                <Icon iconName="paintbrush" />
            </button>
        </StyledComponent>
    )

}

export default Component

const StyledComponent = styled.div<StyledProps>`
    // Styles
`
```

Comment: To be honest.. couldn't find anything that can cause something like that in Color Chooser and Page code... Is there any chance there is another code that causing lots of renders or there might be some forgotten timers?

Comment: No timers, nothing causing re-renders, although obviously if I click fast then it's getting rendered a lot, but the memory should be released. Only thing that makes it slightly better is inlining my pickRandomColor() function, which is just a simple function which picks 3 random values for the H,S and L values of a color. If I click the button more slowly then the JS heap does go down eventually but the nodes count just keeps going up and stays there when I navigate away to a different page.

Comment: It look like this only happens in dev mode. I built the site and clicked as fast as I could for over a minute and no slowdown. The profiler shows that nodes and event listeners are being released often and the JS heap is a sawtooth pattern. I got the idea from this discussion. https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/12141 . I'd still like to understand why this happens so won't add it as an answer yet.

Answer (score 0):

So, It look like this only happens in dev mode. I built the site and clicked as fast as I could for over a minute and no slowdown. The profiler shows that nodes and event listeners are being released often and the JS heap is a sawtooth pattern. I got the idea from this discussion. github.com/facebook/react/issues/12141